# PHP Replace text to random array from substitutes

Tags: php, string, str-replace

How to replace "City1" with random city on $substitutes

```
<?php 
$placeholders = 'City1 - City2 - City3 - City4';
$substitutes  = [
'City1' => ['Orlando,Dallas,Atlanta,Detroit'],
'City2' => ['Jakarta,Bandung,Surabaya'],
'City3' => ['Atlanta,Tampa,Miami'],
'City4' => ['Mandalay,Caloocan,Hai Phong,Quezon City'],
];
$replacements = [];
foreach($substitutes as $key => $choices) {
    $random_key = array_rand($choices);
    $replacements[$key] = $choices[$random_key];
}
$spun = str_replace(
    array_keys($replacements),
    array_values($replacements),
    $placeholders
);
echo $spun;
?>
```

And some output: Dallas - Jakarta - Miami - Mandalay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$substitutes` array is not defined correctly. Try:

```
$substitutes = [
  'City1' => ['Orlando', 'Dallas', 'Atlanta', 'Detroit'],
  'City2' => ['Jakarta', 'Bandung', 'Surabaya'],
  'City3' => ['Atlanta', 'Tampa', 'Miami'],
  'City4' => ['Mandalay', 'Caloocan', 'Hai Phong', 'Quezon City']
];
```

Or if, for some reason, you can't change how `$substitutes` is defined, you can do the following to transform it into the proper form:

```
$substitutes = array_map(function ($cities) {
  return explode(',', $cities[0]);
}, $substitutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way as well.

```
$substitutes  = [
'City1' => ['Orlando','Dallas','Atlanta','Detroit'],
'City2' => ['Jakarta','Bandung','Surabaya'],
'City3' => ['Atlanta','Tampa','Miami'],
'City4' => ['Mandalay','Caloocan','Hai Phong','Quezon City'],
];

foreach($substitutes as $city=>$cities){

  $results[] = $substitutes[$city][array_rand($cities)];

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Atlanta
    [1] => Bandung
    [2] => Miami
    [3] => Hai Phong
)
```

You can add this line and it will output it as a string if you want.

```
$string = implode(' - ', $results);
echo $string;
```

Like so:

```
Atlanta - Bandung - Miami - Hai Phong
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 <?php 
    $placeholders = 'City1 - City2 - City3 - City4';
    $substitutes  = [
    'City1' => ['Orlando,Dallas,Atlanta,Detroit'],
    'City2' => ['Jakarta,Bandung,Surabaya'],
    'City3' => ['Atlanta,Tampa,Miami'],
    'City4' => ['Mandalay,Caloocan,Hai Phong,Quezon City'],
    ];
    $replacements = [];

    foreach($substitutes as $key => $choices) {
    $element = $choices[0];
    $elements=explode(',',$element);
    $randomElement = $elements[array_rand($elements, 1)];


        $placeholders= str_replace($key, $randomElement ,$placeholders);

    }
    echo $placeholders;
    ?>
```

It will produce the output as

```
Orlando - Bandung - Tampa - Hai Phong
```

Comment: in This case you no need to do any changes in your substitutes

Answer (score 0):

How to make this spun result unique ?